# Setting up KnowRob in Ubuntu 12.10 groovy

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I install knowrob from
git clone http://code.in.tum.de/git/ias-common.git ias_common
svn co http://code.in.tum.de/pubsvn/knowrob/tags/latest knowrob
but

I can not install system dependencies and build the KnowRob stack with rosdep satisfy knowrob

rosdep: error: Unsupported command satisfy.

What should I do ?
Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61470/setting-up-knowrob-in-ubuntu-12.10-groovy/) by [saranya](https://answers.ros.org/users/4524/saranya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosdep arguments have changed, it should be 'rosdep install knowrob' by now.

best
Moritz

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2013-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0